# How to create .ipa and generate link to install and test iOS app with extension of watchkit app?

Tags: ios

I am newbie in development of iOS app with extension of watchkit app. Can anybody please help me out by giving a solution of " How to create .ipa of iOS app with extension of watchkit app and generate link to install. I tried to create and install on real device but it didn't work. I was using www.diawi.com for creating this".Your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have to tried to sync it from iTunes? There is a bug in ios9+diawi combination which doesn't allow apps to install. Please specify which iOS version you are targeting.

Comment: Xcode can handle all of this. Create archive and do ad hoc publish.

Comment: Yeah i tried on iTunes and it worked but what do i do if want to share this  with anyone . I am targetting 8.0.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. You can ask others to download the .ipa file from diawi on a system and then sync it with itunes, until there is a solution for that. That's how i am doing currently.